# How to add MultiColumnCombo box add in C# windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I want to use **MultiColumn combo box** in **C# windows application** in **visual studio 2015**. I'm searched and got some **.dll** file, it's not supported and mostly received **vb .dll** file references. Please help this solution. Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Is it a Winform or WPF application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have another example:

[multiColumn combobox](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/winforms-multi-column-combo-box-in-a-datagridview/)

Maybe it helps too.

Comment: @developer I'm glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Multi Column ComboBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3206/Multi-Column-ComboBox)

Hope that helps